# Unmarshal XML to different objects depending on Attribute using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to unmarshal the following XML:

```
<calcElement partname="driver">
    <driverXs>300.00</driverXs>
    <seq>1</seq>
</calcElement>
<calcElement partname="ratingData">
    <baseMiles>6000</baseMiles>
    <vehicleGroup>15</vehicleGroup>
    <documentVersion>4</documentVersion>
</calcElement>
```

I have the following classes, which represent the 2 above instances of calcElement:

```
public abstract class CalcElement {

    private String partName;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String getPartName() {
        return partName;
    }

    public void setPartName(String partName) {
        this.partName = partName;
    }
}

public class DriverCalcElement extends CalcElement {
    private String driverXs;
    private String seq;

    public String getDriverXs() {
        return driverXs;
    }

    public void setDriverXs(String driverXs) {
        this.driverXs = driverXs;
    }

    public String getSeq() {
        return seq;
    }

    public void setSeq(String seq) {
        this.seq = seq;
    }
}

public class RatingDataCalcElement extends CalcElement {
    private String baseMiles;
    private String vehicleGroup;
    private String documentVersion;

    public String getBaseMiles() {
        return baseMiles;
    }

    public void setBaseMiles(String baseMiles) {
        this.baseMiles = baseMiles;
    }

    public String getVehicleGroup() {
        return vehicleGroup;
    }

    public void setVehicleGroup(String vehicleGroup) {
        this.vehicleGroup = vehicleGroup;
    }

    public String getDocumentVersion() {
        return documentVersion;
    }

    public void setDocumentVersion(String documentVersion) {
        this.documentVersion = documentVersion;
    }
}
```

However I am unable to work out the combination of Annotations to add to the classes to successfully unmarshal (and marshal) this code.

What do I need to add to the classes to get this to work?

Comment: You could do this with an `XmlAdapter`: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/01/jaxb-and-inhertiance-using-xmladapter.html

Comment: I did ask the question in a different way here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35012155/xmljavatypeadapter-not-calling-typeadapter and then answered it, even if it was not the most elegant solution.  I didn't realise that I had to do it from a higher level... I will clean this up by deleting this question (as it is answered in other places) later

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do isn't supported natively by JAXB. [XML Schema 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative) introduced the concept of a type alternative which you could use for determining the type of your element with an XPath expression, using the value of attributes on that element, but this isn't supported by JAXB 2.x (which is based on XML Schema 1.0).

You can do something similar with JAXB using [xsi:type](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#xsi_type), but you would either need to change your document on disk or do a transform (e.g. using XSLT) to include the `xsi:type` attribute before passing it to the JAXB Unmarshaller. The values of `xsi:type` would be the type names you assign with your annotations. See the [@XmlType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlType.html) annotation for how the type names of your classes are computed.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I could do something with TypeAdapter, but I couldn't get it to work.  obviously this is the reason why.